# minimal dynamical systems

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $H$ be compact and $\phi$ be surjective and continuous. I want to prove, if $(H,\phi^2)$ is minimal then $(H,\phi)$ is minimal.

Since $(H,\phi^2)$ is minimal, for any $x\in H$, $orb_{\phi^2}(x)$ is dense, though I don't see why $(H,\phi)$ is minimal. I can consider $orb_{\phi}(x)$ but don't know how to proceed further.

Moreover, is the converse true? I think it's not especially if $H$ is disconnected.

Any hint/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\text{orb}_{\phi}(x) &= \{\phi^{m}(x) \, \mid \, m \in \mathbb{N}\} \\
&\supseteq \{\phi^{2m}(x) \, \mid \, m \in \mathbb{N}\} \\
&= \{(\phi^{2})^{m}(x) \, \mid \, m \in \mathbb{N} \} \\
&= \text{orb}_{\phi^{2}}(x).
\end{align*}
Hence, if $\text{orb}_{\phi^{2}}(x)$ is dense, then so is $\text{orb}_{\phi}(x)$.  From this, we see that if $(H,\phi^{2})$ is minimal, then so must be $(H,\phi)$.

The converse is not true.  A simple counterexample is $H = \{0,1\}$ and $\phi(n) = n + 1 \, \text{mod} \, 2$.  $(H,\phi)$ is minimal, but $(H,\phi^{2})$ is not.